Building docker file which fails due to chromadb install
While using pip to install chromadb I got this error ERROR: Could not build wheels for chroma-hnswlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects. I was able to solve it using this method https://github.com/chroma-core/chroma/issues/250#issuecomment-1540934224. However, when I began to work in a docker Environment I got the same error.
I already attempted to add the vairbles below to my dockerfile but that gave me this error
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
ENV HNSWLIB_NO_NATIVE=1
RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

I also added hnswlib to my requiremnts.txt file which also failed.
This is my full dockerfile

FROM python:3.12-slim

EXPOSE 8000

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1


ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1


COPY requirements.txt .
ENV HNSWLIB_NO_NATIVE=1
RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app


RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser


CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "-k", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "new:app"]


If you read your error message you will see that it fails because pip can't find your requirements.txt (and therefore it won't install your dependencies).
You need to copy it into your image.
ENV HNSWLIB_NO_NATIVE=1
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-chache-dir --upgrade pip setuptools
RUN pip install --no-chache-dir -r requirements.txt


thanks I did copy the file but put the install above it. But I now have this error
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c python -m pip install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

You might be missing some build tools.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential -y

works but I now have the original error about the chroma install
